# XBRL R package reads adds another link to input link. Resulting in a link that cannot be opened

Tags: r, xbrl, edgar

I'm using XBRL package to import XBRL data from the SEC EDGAR website, and whenever I use xbrlDoAll function, it is unable to read the url, even though I provided the valid one. For example, to replicate this error, use the following:

```
library(XBRL)

inst <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/aapl-20180929.xml"
xbrl.vars <- xbrlDoAll(inst)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error in fileFromCache(file) : Error in download.file(file, cached.file, quiet = !verbose) : cannot open URL 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/https://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2018/dei-2018-01-31.xsd'
```

As you can see, the URL cannot be opened because for some reason it adds another https:// in the middle of the link to get the file.

> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/https://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2018/dei-2018-01-31.xsd

Which makes it an invalid url. I tried to manually download the file to the cache folder but the issue still persists. How can I edit it so it can properly read and download the content from the links? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug.

Just as a wild guess I would try to use a slightly modified url: `http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/aapl-20180929.xml`.

Using `http` instead of `https`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug as the package has not been maintained very well.  What you need to do is go straight to this website:  https://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2018/dei-2018-01-31.xsd  and then save it directly into your xbrl.Cache folder (or whichever folder is serving as your cache).